# Get video item from list with Url with Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, item

right now I have the Url from a video item, that im showing in a Video native webpart, but i need to get the title and description for processing.

For that, I only can use Javascript, so, I get the List ID like this:

```
function(siteUrl, webUrl, relativeFileUrl, itemResult) {
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var site = ctx.get_site();
            var web = site.openWeb(webUrl);         
            var file = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFileUrl);
            var item = file.get_listItemAllFields();            
            var list = item.get_parentList();
            ctx.load(web);
            //ctx.load(item, 'Id');
            ctx.load(item);
            ctx.load(list);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args){
                    // success
                    //console.log("Success");               
                    itemResult({  
                        list : list,
                        item : item
                    });
                }), 
                Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
                    // error
                    ...
                })
            );
        }
```

But when i check the sharepoint model, it creates two items for the video types, so the Title and description are associated with  a second element, and this function only bring me the first element, that its like a folder, and when you modify the item, you modify its the second element.

There is any way I can get the Title and Description for the video having this item?
Or there is maybe other approach for getting it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you need the actual video stored within the folder. See if this helps: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114846/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-video-uploaded-to-asset-library-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks, the info helps, and I'm using now `web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFileUrl)` and `file.get_properties()` and with that I get `Title` and `description`, but cannot find `LikesCount` Any idea how i get it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I done it now, it was not a property when the element doesn't have a like. Now You know a way to set a like with this method or other `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike` to a folder?

Comment: Please ask another question for that. It is not related to this question. Added answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting comment as answer*
If I'm understanding this right, you need the actual video stored within the folder. Video content type is created as a folder in the asset library. You can use getfolderbyserverrelativeurl and get video  information from there.  See: [How to get the full url of video uploaded to asset library SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114846/how-to-get-the-full-url-of-video-uploaded-to-asset-library-sharepoint)